# Is there a way to upload a video from my iPhone to Google+?

Tags: iphone, video, google-apps

is there a way to upload video from iphone to Google+?

From iphone Google+ app we can upload photos but Video option is only available for Android yet

Comment: Nope - the current version won't call up the video camera - only still mode. It also filters out all video from the film roll when selecting media. You'll have to use the share function or use another app like posterous, vimeo, or other app to get your footage to the net, then link it in.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do that yet. Using external apps won't help either since Google has not released a full API yet with those functions so far.